# Tomcat logging monitoring - identifing errors on build script

Tags: java, tomcat, build, gradle

We are using gradle for our build procedure which does all sorts of exotic operations.
One of our goals right now is to allow automatic rollback on tomcat startup error.

How exactly can our gradle task identify if the tomcat started up correctly (and all of its webapps)?
The naively idea is to actually lookup the .log file and search any error in it.

This might work, but how exactly monitoring the .log file can be achieved ? I find using grep extremely amateurish for this purpose. are there any tools for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can query tomcat for status of a deployed application in similar way as tomcat does it on manager/html site. Grep could used as a secondary solution. I don't know if tomcat exposes API for such monitoring but this is the field that needs some research. Also have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242958/best-tools-to-monitor-tomcat).